# Хранение ацикличного графа в файле

Tags: java, графы

Ищу альтернативу БД в своём приложении, нужна быстрая запись и поиск по строкам. Рассматриваю вариант с библиотекой MDAG https://github.com/klawson88/MDAG. Объект MDAG можно создавать из коллекции и из файла, но если создавать из файла .txt и осуществлять поиск, то получается слишком долго.

```
MDAG mdag = new MDAG(new File("file.txt"));
MDAG mdag1 = new MDAG(new ArrayList<>());
```

Может кто-то подскажет, можно ли сохранить файл со структурой графа и быстро получить к нему доступ или вообще другой способ хранения?

Comment: Каков объем данных? Не проще загружать все в память и работать с ней?

Comment: @Kromster файлы на несколько МБ и их много, в памяти хранить точно не пойдет(

Comment: Если вам нельзя использовать БД, то вам просто придется написать свою "БД". Используя примерно те же принципы. Вообще у вас вопрос какой-то расплывчатый.

Answer (score 0):

> но если создавать из файла .txt и осуществлять поиск, то получается слишком долго.

- Значит создавайте не из текстового, а из бинарного (если он в MDAG есть).
- Слишком долго это сколько, на что тратиться время, на чтение файла или на парсинг? Если на чтение, то тут ничего не поделать. Если на парсинг - копайте в сторону вариантов более быстрого парсинга. Если на поиск - добавляйте индексацию.

> можно ли сохранить файл со структурой графа и быстро получить к нему доступ

конечно можно, но тут вопрос в том, что такое "быстро" в вашем понимании (см. выше).

> или вообще другой способ хранения?

Не изобретать велосипед и использовать локальную БД (например SQLite)

Comment: Да, много времени тратится именно на парсинг... "быстро" - это в пределах секунды желательно. Спасибо за Ваш ответ, рассмотрю другие варианты

Comment: Ускорить парсинг можно если изучить его потроха и понять на что тратится время. По идее, парсинг должен быть быстрее чтения с диска.